# Davar charifs and chometz

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, chametz-leaven, keilim

"Davar charif" is a term in kashrus which refers, as I understand it, to sharp or caustic foods which may absorb flavor from a knife used to cut them, rendering them, say, fleishig if the knife is fleishig.

Does the concept of "davar charif" have any bearing on Pesach kashrus? For example, if a perfectly clean knife that was used for chometz cuts a davar charif, is the davar charif now chometz?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A6%D7%95_%D7%93